# Error while connecting big query in GCP using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery

I was trying to connect Google big query using pySpark using the below code :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("GCP")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
master = "yarn"


spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local")\
    .appName("GCP") \
        .getOrCreate()

spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile","key.json")


df = spark.read.format('bigquery') \
    .option("parentProject", "project_name") \
    .option('table', 'project_name.table_name') \
    .load()
 df.show()
```

my spark version 2.3 and big query jar : spark-bigquery-latest_2.12

Though my service account was having "BigQuery Job User" permission at project level and bigquery data viewer and bigquery user at dataset level , but still I am getting the below error when trying to execute the above code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lo815/GCP/gcp.py", line 23, in <module>
    df.show()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 350, in show
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.showString.
: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: request failed: the user does not have 'bigquery.readsessions.create' permission for 'projects/GCP'
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:53)
```

Comment: In Spark, the BigQuery Storage API is used when reading data from BigQuery and it needs the `bigquery.readsessions.*` permissions. Because, when `BigQuery User` is applied at the project level, you will get access to run queries, create datasets, read dataset metadata, and list tables. But when applied at the dataset level, you will get access only to read dataset metadata and list tables within the dataset. So, could you add the `bigquery.readsessions.*` permissions to your service account(SA) and let me know if it works?

Comment: Thank you Vishal for your reply. I have asked the admin team to check this as I am not the owner of this service account. But I remember that they tried to give this SA 'editor' permission, but we still got the same error. Is editor not a super role that bigquery.readsession

Comment: Also they have added BigQuery User and bigquery dataviewer at dataset level.

Comment: [Editor](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-basic-roles#project-basic-roles) role in BigQuery also doesn’t have `bigquery.readsessions.*` permissions. If you add the `BigQuery User` role at the project level, you will get all the predefined permissions as mentioned in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.user). But, If you add the `BigQuery User` role at the dataset level, you will get only a limited set of permissions. For your requirement, can you try adding the ‘BigQuery User’ role at the project level and let me know if it works.